# How does the () and [] come into play with regex?

Tags: regex

What will be the answer to r(ege)+x and r[ege]+x?
Will the answer be same for both?

Comment: Why don't you try both out (http://www.regex101.com) ?  Answer: They're not the same, because `(ege)` means match and capture `ege` while `[ege]` means match a single letter which is either `e` or `g`.

Comment: `()` is a capturing group (everything inside is matched and put in a capturing group), `[]` is a class of characters (only one of the proposed ones is matched).

Answer (score 0):

the `r(ege)+x` expression will match the letter `r` followed by one or more sets of the string of letters `ege` followed by the letter `x`

Possible matches would be "regex", "regeegex", "regeegeegex", and so on.

The expression `r[ege]+x` will match the letter `r` followed by one or more of any of the letters in the square brackets, followed by the letter `x`.

Possible matches would be "rex", "rgx", "reeex", "rgggx", "regegeggggx", etc.  In the square bracketed expression, the second "e" is redundant, by the way.

You can test expressions using a site like http://regex101.com or similar.